# grunt autoprefixer configuration

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, vendor-prefix

I have a few grunt tasks running, including **grunt-autoprefixer**. All tasks are running without errors, so is the autoprefixer task. But there are no prefixes added to my css rules. What do I miss / misunderstand? 
My Gruntfile options:

```
autoprefixer: {
    options: {
      browsers: ['ie > 7', 'ff > 3.4'] //just to test task
    },
    src: '<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/*.css',
    dest: '<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/*.css'
},
```

Then I run `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer'); grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'sass', 'autoprefixer', 'watch']);`
And as I mentioned without any Errors - so far.
4 sourcefiles are in my cssDir and console also shows 4 files processed

CSS rules which could be prefixed: e.g. `box-shadow, border-radius, linear-gradient`

But no changes are made in my css files not prefixes added. 
Help? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try that and also make sure `globalConfig.cssDir` variable is set correctly:

```
autoprefixer: {
    options: {
        browsers: ['ie > 7', 'ff > 3.4'] //just to test task
    },
    multiple_files: {
        src: '<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/*.css',
        dest: '<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/'
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. `multiple_file` did it plus I had to cancel the destination folder so current files are overwritten..

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel the destination" ?